# Boostrap Calender not working inside asp.net gridview?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, bootstrap-4

I have one grid view , inside I have 3 columns. I would like pop up bootstrap calendar any one of the column. my design is below.

Grid view template

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="input-group date" id="lblLastServiceDate1">
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxLastServiceDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

javascrip function:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#lblLastServiceDate1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });



    });

</script>
```

And I have added all bootstrap file in my page.

its working fine in first row grid view textbox but its not work for 2nd, 3rd and consecutive rows in grid view.

And if anyone faced same issue, please do let me know the answer.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: its because you have call js for only  $('#lblLastServiceDate1') please check id of lblLastServiceDate1 in all rows (firtst ,second,third ,ect)
use class base jq

Answer (score 0):

give it in cssclass like this

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" CssClass="cal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".cal").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1990:2100",
            dateFormat: 'd-M-y'

        });
    });
        </script>
```

[Links for Datepicker UI design](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_datepicker.htm)

Comment: no .. not working dude. do u have any code for populating calendar in gridview?

Comment: <script type="text/css">
             $(function () {
            $(".cal").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "1990:2100",
                dateFormat: 'd-M-y' }); });  </script>                                                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
 <div class="input-group date" id="lblLastServiceDate1">
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbxLastServiceDate" runat="server" CssClass="cal"></asp:TextBox> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa calendar"></span></span

Comment: u used  <script type="text/css"> u need <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: and Click on the Right arrow if the answer solved the Problem

Comment: <link href="~/dist/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/dist/js/moment.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/dist/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: i m using above bootstrap file

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#lblLastServiceDate1').datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            });       

        });

    </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".cal").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1990:2100",
            dateFormat: 'd-M-y'

        });
    });
        </script>

Comment: and above javascript. that's include yours also

Comment: copy paste this remove the original one

Comment: My Gridview template like below

Comment: then tell me if it is

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  
                    <div class="input-group date" id="lblLastServiceDate1">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxLastServiceDate" runat="server" CssClass="cal"></asp:TextBox>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: ya remove that and put <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="tbxLastServiceDate" runat="server" CssClass="cal form-control"></asp:TextBox> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: let me try ..  get back to u soon

Comment: tell me exactly whats not working the datepicker or the texbox is not showing?

Comment: i think i need to link correct datapicker css and js

Comment: create a new page just use the gridview with only one textbox then put the jquery code try if it works there

Comment: see there is a link i have given in the answer refer that for the files

Comment: ya sure No problem

Comment: Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'.. i am getting this error

Comment: <ItemTemplate>               
                  <asp:TextBox ID="tbxLastServiceDate" runat="server" CssClass="cal"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>

Comment: <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".cal").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1990:2100",
            dateFormat: 'd-M-y'

        });
    });
        </script>

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                                                        https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js

Comment: click this both rigth click save

Comment: save it dont change name and all just save it then put it in your folder project include it in your project then just drag the file to the aspx page it will give u the link and remove the rest

Comment: I will be back in hour

Comment: see i used it it is working fine i dont understand whats wrong with yours

Comment: try outside gridiview?

Comment: if its working there it should work inside too tell me one thing how did u bind the grid?

Comment: i am binding grid , like below                                                              GridView1.DataSource = biz.GetAllSection();
GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: i ll try outside and let u know

Comment: then is this texbox blank??

Comment: try it outside and tell